# Как сделать динамическую проверку нажатия кнопки в телеграмм?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть кнопка на которую выводится кол-во сообщений из базы данных.

**Вывод клавиатуры "main.py"**

```py
def get_keyboard(message):
    count = db.count_list(message.chat.id)
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    keyboard.add(f"Список - {count[0]}", "/Записать")
    return keyboard
```

**Счётчик сообщений
"db.py"**

```py
def count_list(user_id: int):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("list.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql_count = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_message WHERE user_id = {}".format(
        user_id)
    c.execute(sql_count)
    count = c.fetchone()
    return count
```

Обычно ведь проверка кнопки идёт через условный оператор **if**,вида:`if message.text == "Список'`
Но как проверить кнопку если *на ней* будут всё время меняться данные?

**P.S.** Моя попытка:
`if message.text == f"Список - {db.count_list(message.chat.id)}":` не работает и не выводит никаких ошибок,просто ничего не происходит

Comment: проверяйте есть ли искомое в кнопке: if 'Список' in message.text:

Comment: @D.Violet спасибо, помогло